# How to store data in input box if the specific button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I want to do is when a user click the button it will store the value of the inputboxes to localstorage.

My problem is after i click the button it doesnt store the data to the localstorage if i refreshed the page all inputboxes are empty.

testing link:  http://jsfiddle.net/LgA2m/64/

html:

```
One: <input type="text" name="one" id="one" /> <br />
One Copy:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="OneCopy" id="OneCopy" />
<br />
<button type="button" id="click">Click</button>
```

script:

```
$('#click').click(function(){

$('#one').on("blur keyup change", function () {
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
});

$('#one, #OneCopy').each(function (ind, val) {
    $(val).val(localStorage.getItem($(val).attr("id")));
});

localStorage.setItem($('#OneCopy').attr("id"), $('#one').val());
$('#OneCopy').val(localStorage.getItem($('#one').attr("id")));

});
```

Comment: Do you attempt to reload the values from local storage on page load? I don't see any code that does this... thus they would still be blank. Or does your script run after all the fields are rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rather confusing, you should really try understanding what you have, because I don't think it does what you think it does.

However, I have written some code that does what it sounds like you want:

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("one", $("#one").val());
});

$(function() {
    $('#OneCopy').val(localStorage.getItem('one'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not wrap your listeners inside a listener
every time you click it would create new ones

just this should do it if I understand you right:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem('one', $('#one').val());
  $('#OneCopy').val(localStorage.getItem('one');
});
```